# Why can we not have a group in which AA = BB ≠ E when E is identity of group

Tags: group-theory

I'm not used to group theory.

Can anyone teach me why aa = bb = e?

Comment: What are A2, B2 and E? Giving important definitions means that people will be able to understand your question, and therefore are more likely to answer it

Comment: In some groups, $aa=bb=e$.  In others, not.  Probably you are reading about one particular example of a group.  Without more context, we cannot tell.

Comment: The claim as stated is false is most rings, including the integers. In fact, rings that satisfy this are somewhat special, like $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x,y]$. Even then, thi s is false for the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Did you mean \$a^2\$, which renders $a^2$?

Comment: If you are asking whether there is a group such that $aa=bb$ for all $a,b$ in the group but where $bb\neq e$ for all $b$... obviously this can't happen since $ee=e$ by the very nature of how an identity element of a group acts and $e$ is a valid choice for $b$...  That does not of course mean that $aa=bb=e$ is always true for all $a,b$ however.  It is possible for $aa\neq bb$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $(G, \cdot)$ is a group and $a,b,e\in G$ with $e$ being the identity element.

Without further assumptions, it is *very* rare that $a^2=a\cdot a = e$, since that would mean that $a = a^{-1}$. This does sometimes happen, but is a very special case.

**Some examples.**

If $G = \{0\}$ then it always happens, since $0=e$ is the only element, and indeed, in any group, $e = e^{-1}$.

If $G = \{0,1\}$ with $\cdot$ being addition modulo $2$, so $0\cdot 0 = 1 \cdot 1 = 0$ and $0 \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot 0 = 1$, and $e=0$, then again you see it for every element, since $0 \cdot 0 = e = 1 \cdot 1$.

If $G = \mathbb{Z}$ with ordinary addition, the only element satisfying $a \cdot a  =e$ will be the identity element itself...

Answer (score 1):

Two distinct elements of a group can have equal squares without being involutions (i.e. squaring to the identity). For example, $2^2=(-2)^2=4$ in the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in all groups.  For example, the group on three elements $\{a,b,e\}$ with $e$ the identity has $aa=b, bb=a$